# Switch between 2 views of a recyclerview on a button click in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i've a recyclerview in which i have 2 buttons.i want to switch between 2 different views on clicking the button.in my recyclerview adapter class, i've populated the view as

```
 public Offline_ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
     view=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.offline_data_card, null);
  Offline_ViewHolder ovh = new Offline_ViewHolder(view);
 return ovh;
```

but i dont know how to use 2 views on button click.i've attached the views that i want to switch on button click  [view 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ng2TF.png)

My full code is shown below:

Offline_Adapter.java:

---

```
public class Offline_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Offline_ViewHolder> {
     Context context;
    RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    ImageLoader mImageLoader;
    DBHelper myDB;
    ArrayList<Offers> datas;
    SparseBooleanArray selectedItems;
    ActionMode mActionMode;
    Button b1,b2;
    public Offline_Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<Offers> datas) {

        this.context = context;
        this.datas = datas;
        selectedItems = new SparseBooleanArray();
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue, new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {

            private final LruCache<String, Bitmap> mCache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(10);

            public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                mCache.put(url, bitmap);
            }

            public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                return mCache.get(url);
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public Offline_ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        b1=(Button)parent.findViewById(R.id.b1);
        b2=(Button)parent.findViewById(R.id.b2);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                view = LayoutInflater.from(v.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.offline_data_card, null);
               view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                view = LayoutInflater.from(v.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.offline_data_card_view2, null);
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        Offline_ViewHolder ovh = new Offline_ViewHolder(view);
        return ovh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(Offline_ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        String card_id = datas.get(position).getLe_id().toString();
        String img_url = URL.IMAGE;
        String Thumb_image = img_url + card_id + ".jpg";
        if (Thumb_image == null || Thumb_image == "") {
            holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.vg_placeholder);
        } else {
            holder.image.setImageUrl(Thumb_image, mImageLoader);
        }

        String font_path = "fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf";
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), font_path);
        holder.title.setTypeface(font);
        holder.title.setText(datas.get(position).getTitle().toString());

        String count = datas.get(position).getView_count();
        count = Integer.valueOf(count).toString();
        holder.v_count.setText(count);
        holder.c_count.setText(datas.get(position).getComment_count());
        holder.f_count.setText(datas.get(position).getFav_count());


        holder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String downloadpath = URL.DOWNLOAD;
                String url_id = datas.get(position).getLe_id().toString();
                String download_link = downloadpath + url_id + ".zip";

                String file_title = datas.get(position).getTitle().toString();
                String publishversion = datas.get(position).getPublish_ver().toString();
                String fav = datas.get(position).getFav_count().toString();
                String com = datas.get(position).getComment_count().toString();
                String view = datas.get(position).getView_count().toString();

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, Offline_view.class);
                intent.putExtra("url_id", url_id);
                intent.putExtra("d_url", download_link);
                intent.putExtra("file_title", file_title);
                intent.putExtra("publishV", publishversion);
                intent.putExtra("fav", fav);
                intent.putExtra("com", com);
                intent.putExtra("view", view);


                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return datas.size();
    }
```

---

Offline_ViewHolder.class

---

```
public class Offline_ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    NetworkImageView image;
    TextView title;
    TextView tv1,v_count,c_count,f_count;
    Offline_Adapter adapter;
    public Offline_ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        image=(NetworkImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_thumbnail);
        title=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        v_count= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewcount_txt);
        c_count= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_text);
        f_count= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fav_text);

   }
}
```

[recyclerview with button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxO5F.png)

Comment: can you put your code and explain more ,what you want to achieve?

Comment: i've 2 buttons in a recycler view  and 2 views(view image links are attached in the question).i want to switch between these 2 views on a button clicks.

Comment: what do you mean by 2 buttons in a recycler view? Recycler view have view items which is not  just like other ViewGroups have views in itself. Do you have 2 button item view and two image view items, i.e. total 4 items? can you put your code here? I can help you out

Comment: i've editted my code,u can see the recyclerview with button.i want to switch between these views on clicking that button.is there any other method to switch between 2 view other than adding a button in recyclerview?

Comment: you can add [Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/intl/in/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)

Comment: no i can't use navigation drawer in my app.i want to use a button or image button to change the viewtype

Comment: Hey, check my proposed solution.

Comment: that is not really working.view are mixed up.if u can share me your email id,i can send you my whole code

Comment: mschhimwalk@gmail.com. Would like to help you for sure.

Comment: i,ve sent an email with the complete code.hope u can help me

Comment: Hey your both layout files are same. How do you know even if the code works?

Comment: layout is different in views.one is square type card and another one is rectangular card

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
       if(position==0){
         youbutton.setOnclickListener();
       }else{
       }
    }
```

use position in onBindViewHolder.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong here

```
@Override
    public Offline_ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
        b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b2);
```

And why are you doing  this stuff in onCreateViewHolder() of  RecyclerView Adapter class. From your code it seems these buttons are in Activity or Fragment layouts. Right?
If yes, please find them in Activity fragment and set Click Listener  to them.

Next: make a public method in Adapter class and a state variable in Adapter class too.

```
    public class Offline_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Offline_ViewHolder> {
         Context context;
private boolean mIsOfflineMode = false;

        RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
        ImageLoader mImageLoader;
        DBHelper myDB;
        ArrayList<Offers> datas;
```

and public method in adapter as

```
   public void setOfflineSate(boolean state){
     mIsOfflineMode  = state;
 this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Next: Now time comes to handle view in onCreateViewHolder method of adapter.

```
   @Override
    public Offline_ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view ;
        if(isOffileMode){
        view = LayoutInflater.from(v.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.offline_data_card, null);     
    }else{
     view=LayoutInflater.from(v.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.offline_data_card_view2,null);
    }

     Offline_ViewHolder ovh=new Offline_ViewHolder(view);
        return ovh;
   }
```

Now in your activity or fragment class, handle button click as

```
 // I am supposing you have Offline_Adapter Object as mOffLineAdapter and is  initialized 
 b1=(Button)parent.findViewById(R.id.b1);
        b2=(Button)parent.findViewById(R.id.b2);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             mOffLineAdapter.setOfflineSate(false);
            }
        });
        b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               mOffLineAdapter.setOfflineSate(true);
            }
        });
```